# Android admob in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, admob, android-fragmentactivity

i have a big problem with my new app, I'm using the new FragmentActivity provided by the new ATD Plugin for Eclipse.
The step by step guide has created for me the main FragmentActivity with the 3 section.

This is the code:

```
package com.italiandevteam.chuck;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ChuckActivity extends FragmentActivity{


/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
 * sections. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will
 * keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it may be best
 * to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chuck);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());



    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_chuck, menu);
    return true;
}




/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
 * sections of the app.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section1);
            case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section2);
            case 2: return getString(R.string.title_section3);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                //Create the view
        }
}



}
```

I have insert in the `onCreateView` my switch to show different layout in this way:

```
switch(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){
                case 1:{
                     myView = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.layout_1, null);
                     break;
                }

                case 2:{
                    myView = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.layout_2, null);
                    break;
                }

            }
return myView
```

Now i really need to add admob into my project but if i put this coe in the `onCreate` method

```
AdView adView;

        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14eedc43db2122");

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        request.addTestDevice("B7709F3C1336BFAEFAD6E50877E3211F");

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(request);
```

my app will crash and the logcat:

```
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.italiandevteam.chuck/com.italiandevteam.chuck.ChuckActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at com.italiandevteam.chuck.ChuckActivity.onCreate(ChuckActivity.java:66)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
07-11 10:40:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(4948):     ... 11 more
```

I can't find a way to insert adMob in my project, can you help me?

EDIT:

this is my activity_chuck.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChuckActivity">

    <!--
    This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
    titles for adjacent pages.
    -->
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and this is my layout_1 (it's similar to layout_2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:gravity="top"
     >
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_top" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titolo_scheda"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/biografia"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    >
    </TextView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT 2:
Now with the admob code in the switch it works but just for the first page, if i swipe to the second section i crashed and this is the LogCat:

```
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at com.italiandevteam.chuck.ChuckActivity$DummySectionFragment.onCreateView(ChuckActivity.java:139)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:895)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1539)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:1422)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1562)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6900)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1908)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1527)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1263)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
07-11 14:51:27.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6282):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have put the xml LinearLayout for admob also in the second layout
Here layout_2.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_top" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bryce" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/beckman" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

      <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:gravity="top"
     >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post your layout XMLs too.

Accordingly to your stack trace, `findViewById(R.id.pager)` returns `null`. That means this ID is not defined in `activity_chuck.xml`

Comment: Your layouts look fine.

It says the NullPointerException is happening at  `com.italiandevteam.chuck.ChuckActivity.onCreate(ChuckActivity.java:66)`. What exactly is there (line 66)? Is it `findViewById(R.id.pager)` or something else?

Comment: it is layout.addView(adView); it refear to the whole project with the admob code

Comment: well this is wrong. You have no `@+id/linearlayout` in `activity_chuck.xml` so `findViewById(R.id.linearlayout)` will return `null`. You need to put your AdMob code into your fragment after the `layout_1.xml` or `layout_2.xml` is loaded.

Edit: put it after the switch statement in `onCreateView` and use `myView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout)` to get that container.

Comment: How can i load my admob code after the layout? should i put in my switch?

Comment: Yes, I would try to put it before `return myView`, see my last comment (Edit:)

Comment: I have add it to my switch but now i have this error (in Eclipse) `The constructor AdView(ChuckActivity.DummySectionFragment, AdSize, String) is undefined` it is refered to `adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "myID");`

Comment: A Fragment is not a Context, use `getActivity()` inside Fragments to get a Context.

Comment: Now it works but just for the first section, if i swipe in the second it crashed..see my EDIT 2 in the answer for logcat

Comment: Well, do you have an ID `linearlayout` in `layout_2`?

Comment: so what is on line 139 in ChuckActivity.java?

Comment: it's this again `myView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);`

Comment: so this means `myView` is null, why is it not set by the switch statement? Set a breakpoint on the `switch(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))` line and debug to find out why `myView` is not set.

Comment: The problem is that i can swipe to the second layou and it is displayed but when the second section is completely swipped the app crashed so i think that the problem is no the myView, what you think? EDIT: if i remove the java code for admob the app works

Comment: Well you get a NullPointerException while invoking a method of an object. This means the object reference is `null` which must not happen.
You may want to update your first post with your current code. It's a bit messy right now with all those changes.

Comment: I have added the default option in the switch and now it works, i think that the AdMob code was looking for the linearLayout also for the 3rd layout that i haven been created yet!
For now i can just say thank you for your patience!